# PhpLdapAdmin - How to disable a user/uid?

Tags: openldap, ldap

Using PhpLdapAdmin, how do you disable/lock a user/uid so that it can't be used to login to anything on the network that uses LDAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to just zero the password. You could also add an explicit ACL to deny that user access to the directory (remember, an LDAP authentication triggers a bind call).

You could also add a custom field and update your search filter to only include users where that custom field is correct. I do it this way.